# Не получается установить Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Я пробую установить Visual Studio Codee

Начинается процесс установки и мне вылазит ошибка: [image: ошибка]

Comment: А вы что-то выбирали или оно само? Может у вас переменные окружения какие-то левые, TEMP не на существующий путь указывает, либо ещё какая переменная?

Comment: Оно само путь выбрало почему-то и его я изменить не могу:(